# Half Container, Half Container Fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, positioning

guys, I'm trying to achieve a layout, where I have a container with 2 cols, however, the right col needs to be positioned to the right of the screen, and not to the right of the container... if that makes sense?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            this content is inside the container normally
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            image will go here, but needs to be positioned to the right of the screen, not to the right of the container
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then you need to take it out of the container. What effect are you trying to acheive?

Comment: Certainly **not** possible with bootstrap

Comment: I think a `position:absolute` or  `position:fixed` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting text in `div` and then add class `mr-0` to it.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can do it.

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tg74hrpa/12/)

```
<div class=".parent">
  <div class="child">
    image will go here, but needs to be positioned to the right of the screen, not to the right of the container
  </div>
  <div class="abs">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          this content is inside the container normallythis content is inside the container normally
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```